# Tkintertable Get selected Data

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using tkintertable and want to check which row is selected. Is this possible? 
And I also want to sort the columns and name the columns like I want...

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little late, but figured I would answer this in case anyone else finds this through a google search like I did :P

There are a couple ways to do select data based on mouse clicks.

First you need to bind the mouse click to a callback function, and in this callback function you need to grab the data.  You might need to bind the mouse click on release so that it grabs data when you release the mouse button.

You can use the table.get_row_clicked()/table.get_col_clicked() functions along with model.getValueAt() to do get individual cells.

To get the contents of an entire row in a dictionary where column_name = key & contents of that selected rows column = value, you need to use model.getRecordAtRow(row_index).

Example:

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *
from tkintertable.Tables import TableCanvas
from tkintertable.TableModels import TableModel

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.model = TableModel()
        self.table = TableCanvas(self, model=self.model)
        self.table.createTableFrame()
        root.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.clicked)   #Bind the click release event

        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.table.model.load('save.table')  #You don't have to load a model, but I usually
        self.table.redrawTable()             #Create a base model for my tables.

        d = dir(self.table)  #Will show you what you can do with tables.  add .model
                             #to the end to see what you can do with the models.
        for i in d:
            print i

    def clicked(self, event):  #Click event callback function.
        #Probably needs better exception handling, but w/e.
        try:
            rclicked = self.table.get_row_clicked(event)
            cclicked = self.table.get_col_clicked(event)
            clicks = (rclicked, cclicked)
            print 'clicks:', clicks
        except: 
            print 'Error'
        if clicks:
            #Now we try to get the value of the row+col that was clicked.
            try: print 'single cell:', self.table.model.getValueAt(clicks[0], clicks[1])
            except: print 'No record at:', clicks

            #This is how you can get the entire contents of a row.
            try: print 'entire record:', self.table.model.getRecordAtRow(clicks[0])
            except: print 'No record at:', clicks

root = Tk()
root.title('Table Test')
app = Application(master=root)
print 'Starting mainloop()'
app.mainloop()
```

As far as the other things, you should be able to get info off the wiki:

http://code.google.com/p/tkintertable/wiki/Usage

Some things are a pain to figure out, but it's worth it IMO.  I still can't figure out how to programmatically change the contents of a cell, and that's right on the wiki page, lol.